# When developing a rubygem with C extensions, how do you test locally with Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-c-extension, extconf.rb

I'm writing a gem, that includes a C extension.  Usually when I write a gem, I follow a process of TDD, where I'll write a failing spec and then work on the code until it passes, etc etc...

With my C extension in "ext/mygem/mygem.c" and a valid extconf.rb configured in the gemspec's "extensions", how do I run my specs and still have my C extension loaded?  When I make changes to the C code, what steps do I need to take to recompile the code?

This is probably a stupid question, but typing 'bundle install' from inside my gem's development source tree does not build any native extensions.  When I manually run `ruby ext/mygem/extconf.rb` I do get a Makefile (in the root of the whole project) and when I then run `make`, I do get a shared object (again, in the root of the whole project).  I must be following the wrong workflow, since I understand that the .so is supposed to be placed under lib/.  Unless I'm just supposed to do that by hand during development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I went with in the end was to use rake-compiler, on github:

https://github.com/luislavena/rake-compiler

You just add a rake task to do the compile (documented in the README), then make the 'spec' task(s) depend on that build phase.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know whether it's the 'right' way but the way I've done this in the past is

Add

```
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../ext'
```

To my spec helper

And then have a rakefile that looks like

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new('spec')
task :build do
  Dir.chdir('ext') do
    output = `ruby extconf.rb`
    raise output unless $? == 0
    output = `make`
    raise output unless $? == 0
  end
end

task :spec => :build
```

So `rake spec` builds the c code for me each time, with the built library existing in ext/. The change to the load path ensures that this copy is loaded. This [github repo](https://github.com/fcheung/rubylinear/) illustrates this.

Comment: Thanks :) I was just coming back here to post that I've found "rake-compile" on github.  You basically add it as a development dependency, then in your Rakefile you can tell it what extensions to build.  It will run extconf.rb, make, then copy the lib and cleanup. https://github.com/luislavena/rake-compiler